# what does this rails code do? :on => :member

Tags: ruby-on-rails

please can you explainme what does this code do?

```
resources :products do
 get :who_bought, :on => :member
end
```

the code complete is from the book pragmatig programing, but it not explain why we use that code, ":on => :member""

```
Depot::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :orders



resources :line_items
 post 'line_items/decrease'


resources :carts


get "store/index"

resources :products do
   get :who_bought, :on => :member
end

root :to => 'store#index', :as => 'store'
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

passing `:on => :member` means that you are working on a specific record in the database, in this case products. so the url that route generates is

`/products/:id/who_bought`

which means that you want the get the product whose id is :id and process the who_bought action.  the counterpart, `:on => :collection`, expects the action to work on a list of products so the url will look like

`/products/who_bought`

if you change member to collection.  you can see that the route doesn't require an :id passed because it doesn't expect you to work on a single record.